# Print Number N times from array with Python

Tags: python, arrays, printing, int

I've seen several examples of printing a string multiple times and can't find the solution to print out an int multiple times.

I have two arrays.

I want to print out 1, 1 time 3,2 times and 4, 2 times.
I know I can't use the * operator as I would to print a string n times

How can I get to

```
[1,3,3,4,4]
```

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
A = [1, 3, 4]
B = [1, 2, 2]
i = 0
j = 0
for i in range(0, len(A), 1):
    for j in range(0, len(B), 1):
        if i==j:
            print A[i] * B[j]
```

UPDATE: I edited the code to reflect actual numbers since I tested one code and posted another. Sorry about that.

Comment: That's not the code you actually ran; if it were, you would have gotten [this output](http://ideone.com/SryqZJ). We need to see code you actually ran, not code that's equally wrong in different ways.

Comment: Do you want to print a list of numbers with some repetition or do you want to build a list with that frequency of each number?  Can you edit the question to show the desired output?

Comment: user2357112 You're right, I had tested one piece of code and posted another. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

another alternative with list comprehensions

```
[e for e,c in zip(a,b) for i in range(c)]
[1, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

or, more hacky

```
sum([[e]*c for e,c in zip(a,b)],[])
[1, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

Comment: I like your first solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend an empty list using a list comprehension.  Zip together your two lists `A` and `B` to treat them in parallel.

```
result = []
_ = [result.extend([a] * b) for a, b in zip(A, B)]

>>> result
[1, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

**EDIT**

A list comprehension should only be used for creating a list, not its side effects.  Better to use a loop in the example above.

```
result = []
for a, b in zip(A, B):
    result.extend([a] * b)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a lot of extra things in your code you don't need.

```
A=[1,3,4]
B=[1,2,2]
"""first loop over the elements you want to print in A"""
for i in range(len(A)):
    """ A[i] j times """
    for j in range(B[i]):
        print A[i]
```

I would suggest reading up on how the range function works in python https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

also if you want to add those values to an array, you must first define that array then add them to it rather than printing them.

```
A=[1,3,4]
B=[1,2,2]
result=[]
"""first loop over the elements you want to print in A"""
for i in range(len(A)):
    """ append A[i] to result j times """
    for j in range(B[i]):
        result.append(A[i])

print str(result)
```

Comment: I see, thanks! Ya this gives what I want but I would like to print A[i] ultimately to get 1,3,3,4,4 so I just edited it to : for j in range(B[i]):
        print A[i]